# Can this switch statement be shortened?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, allegro, allegro5

Could this switch statement be shortened? Is it proper way of doing this? It is a simple thing and I don't know if there is a sense to use switch.

This part of code iterates through an array to take value of intesivity of color(form 0 to about 10) and draw a square with this color using allegro library. So for 7 and more it will be black, for less it will be grey and for 1 it will be very light grey.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int value = cells[i + j * 50];
        if(value > 0) {
            unsigned char color;
            switch (value) {
                case 1 :
                     color = 200;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    color = 180;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    color = 140;
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    color = 100;
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    color = 60;
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    color = 40;
                    break;
                case 7 :
                    color = 20;
                    break;
                default: color = 0;
            }
            al_draw_filled_rectangle(i * 8, 400 - (j * 8), i * 8 + 8, 400 - (j * 8 + 8),
                                     al_map_rgb(color, color, color));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `value` and `color` have a pretty simple relationship that could be expressed with an equation.

Comment: oh sorry it was my mistake with value = 5. They are just random numbers, idea is just to make higher number of color for lower value

Comment: Why not make a relationship so that you can do a simple mathematical expression instead of a switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookup table instead of `switch` statement

```
static const unsigned char COLORS[] = { 0, 200, 180, 140, 100, 60, 40, 20 };

unsigned char color = 
  value >= 0 && value < sizeof COLORS / sizeof *COLORS ? COLORS[value] : 0;
```

Comment: That is nice but I have got a warning: values type const int may not fit into receiver type unsigned char. I think that is because of 0 at the end

Comment: ": (unsigned char )0;" helps but I guess that it is not a proper way of doing this

Comment: And I have got this:
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                         value **<** sizeof(COLORS) ? COLORS[value] : (unsigned char )0;

Comment: @Mateusz that is probably a hint that `value` needs to be unsigned. Is there any particular reason you're using a signed type here?

Comment: yes because value is an amount of intensity of colour that is positive.

Answer (score 3):

It can be rewritten as follows:

```
int colors[]={100,80,60,40,20};
for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int value = cells[i + j * 50];
        unsigned int color=0;
        color=colors[value];          
    }
}
```

Comment: if the value will be 7 then we will go out of array index

Comment: This is just an example. You could make your array larger, or check the index before looking up the value, etc..

Comment: You need to add an `if` (or e.g. call to `min`) to handle the `default:`.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you shorten the switch. You just have to waste 7 lines populating your map:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int color;
  int value;
  cout << "Enter a color value 1-7: ";
  cin >> value;

  map<int, int> colormap;
  colormap[1] = 200;
  colormap[2] = 180;
  // etc...                                                                                                                            

  color = colormap[value];
  cout << "color = " << color << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is worse than the switch